# How to get specific values from rows in multidimensional arrays using 2 column as filter

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this

```
 String[][] array = {{"A", "1"},
                     {"B", "1"},
                     {"C", "2"},
                     {"D", "2"},
                     {"E", "1"}};
```

And I don't know how to get two strings using 2nd column values

```
string one : A,B,E    for 1
string two : C,D      for 2
```

Comment: What did you try to do? Please share what you tried so we can help.

Comment: Do know how to iterate arrays using loops? Do you know how to check two Strings are equal? Do you know how to concatenate Strings? Which part of this task is it you are struggling with?

Comment: Hint. You can use map to store key-value pairs while looping through array.

Comment: @MilosStojanovic I feel this would be overkill here - I *guess* that the task is to just build the String iteratively in a simple loop, no need for additional data structures. But to be sure, we need more context.

Comment: Maybe, I mentioned map because maybe values in second column are not fixed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use Hash Map approach here. If you are unaware about it, it's a data structure which stores key and value pairs (for eg - A:apple,B:ball,etc).

```
Map<String, StringBuilder> resultMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (String[] entry : array) {
            String key = entry[1];
            resultMap.putIfAbsent(key, new StringBuilder());
            resultMap.get(key).append(entry[0]).append(",");
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, StringBuilder> entry : resultMap.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue().toString();
            if (value.endsWith(",")) {
                value = value.substring(0, value.length() - 1);
            }
            System.out.println("string " + key + ": " + value);
```

You might want to alter the code according to your required format.

Comment: It's nice of you to provide solution to his problem, but the idea is that person who ask question first provide his attempt of solving problem and then to discuss further improving or correcting that solution. Also, you are missing closing bracket for second for loop.